# Basic popup in dojo 1.7

Tags: popup, dojo, dijit.form

Hi so im playing with dojo and I looked at popup documentation and I don't understand all of it. So i Have a onClick event that I would like to use to open the popup.

```
else if (e.cell.identifier == 'calendar'){
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

So here is a part of my conditional statement and in my else if statement I want it to run my popup when I click on the cell. Is it possible and if so how would I do that.

P.S. I have already required dijit/popup.

The alert box is there to test if my else statement is work (which it is).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to create the widget you want to popup and then you need open your popup. NOTE: You must attach the popup to an element

```
else if (e.cell.identifier == 'calendar')
{
     var calendar = new dijit.Calendar({
                                            value: new Date()
                                       });

      popup.open(
        {
            popup: calendar,
            around: dojo.byId("a div's id")
        });
}
```